# dbus_bus_request_name (): Connections are not allowed to own the service

Tags: linux, dbus, busybox, avahi

I built a root filesystem on arm. It should run dbus-daemon and avahi-daemon, but when I try to run `avahi-daemon`

```
$ dbus-daemon --system
$ avahi-daemon
```

I get this message:

```
Found user 'avahi' (UID 4) and group 'avahi' (GID 4).
Successfully dropped root privileges.
avahi-daemon 0.6.28 starting up.
WARNING: No NSS support for mDNS detected, consider installing nss-mdns! 
dbus_bus_request_name(): Connection ":1.0" is not allowed to own the service "org.freedesktop.Avahi" due to security policies in the configuration file
WARNING: Failed to contact D-Bus daemon.
avahi-daemon 0.6.28 exiting.
```

What is wrong? Is it about dbus configuration ?

Comment: Tell us how you did configure dbus & avahi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem, in my case the default avahi-dbus.conf that come with my system packet system just lack the last  " `</policy>` " before  " `</busconfig>` " which triggered this error.

I first thought the problem didn't come from this file since a rapid look at it is not enough to find this kind of syntax error.

Answer (score 25):

In my case I simply had to restart the dbus service.

This probably was because avahi inserted a dbus config file (`/etc/dbus-1/system.d/avahi-dbus.conf`) which wasn't detected automatically.

Comment: Yup, me too. This is a current Arch Linux bug that happens after you install avahi but before dbus is restarted (either through systemctl or a reboot) https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/55738

Answer (score 21):

There are restrictions on what client can register what name on the system bus. Otherwise a user process could receive request intended for some system service.
The restrictions are configured via the dbus-daemon configuration file, usually `/etc/dbus-1/system.conf`. In standard installations this file includes other config files, especially all in the `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/` directory, where service specific configurations are stored. This way DBus is usually configured for Avahi:

Example from my workstation:

```
$ cat /etc/dbus-1/system.d/avahi-dbus.conf 
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
          "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
          "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>

  <!-- Only root or user avahi can own the Avahi service -->
  <policy user="avahi">
    <allow own="org.freedesktop.Avahi"/>
  </policy>
  <policy user="root">
    <allow own="org.freedesktop.Avahi"/>
  </policy>

  <!-- Allow anyone to invoke methods on Avahi server, except SetHostName -->
  <policy context="default">
    <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.Avahi"/>
    <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.Avahi"/>

    <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.Avahi"
          send_interface="org.freedesktop.Avahi.Server" send_member="SetHostName"/>
  </policy>

  <!-- Allow everything, including access to SetHostName to users of the group "adm" -->
  <policy group="adm">
    <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.Avahi"/>
    <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.Avahi"/>
  </policy>
  <policy user="root">
    <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.Avahi"/>
    <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.Avahi"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```

Make sure you have these standard configuration files or a proper custom configuration in place.

Comment: how does the avahi daemon know to use this .conf file for its dbus? or are all config files loaded and thrown into a pool of rules, so that adding another .conf file would modify permissions for connections to org.freedesktop.Avahi?