# System D-Bus does not allow punching out ownership with conf files

Tags: linux, configuration, dbus, qtdbus

I am trying to create a daemon service that runs on the system bus where the permissions for sending and receiving from this service should be completely open to anybody. (Security is not a concern for this service). When I attempt to register the service using QtDbus (using the PyQt for it) I get this error: `Connection ":1.0" is not allowed to own the service "org.dbus.arduino" due to security policies in the configuration file`. This other stack overflow has the same error, but does not help at all in this situation for some reason. [`dbus_bus_request_name ()`: Connections are not allowed to own the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560877/dbus-bus-request-name-connections-are-not-allowed-to-own-the-service).

Normally you're supposed to leave the `system.conf` file in-tact and add your permissions "punch out" config file in the `system.d` directory. I have done this, but it does not seem to change anything, regardless with how open I make the permissions. In fact I'm almost positive it's not changing anything! Here is my conf file as it sits right this moment.

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">

<busconfig>
    <policy user="myUser">
        <allow own="*"/>
        <allow own="org.dbus.arduino"/>
        <allow send_type="method_call" log="true"/>
    </policy>                 
    <policy user="root">        
        <allow own="*"/>
        <allow own="org.dbus.arduino"/>
        <allow send_type="method_call" log="true"/>
    </policy>                         
    <policy context="default">            
    </policy>                                                     
</busconfig>
```

Even if I do this or things like it, it STILL doesn't work.

```
<busconfig>               
    <policy context="default">     
        <allow own="*"/>
        <allow own="org.dbus.arduino"/>
        <allow send_type="method_call" log="true"/>       
    </policy>                                                     
</busconfig>
```

I even put the name of the file starting with a z so that it may be the very last one that is read in. Here is the system.conf file, note where I have commented out the "allow own" section. This is the ONLY way to get this to work (and the worst possible "fix").

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-Bus Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>

  <!-- Our well-known bus type, do not change this -->
  <type>system</type>

  <!-- Run as special user -->
  <user>messagebus</user>

  <!-- Fork into daemon mode -->
  <fork/>

  <!-- We use system service launching using a helper -->
  <standard_system_servicedirs/>

  <!-- This is a setuid helper that is used to launch system services -->
  <servicehelper>/lib/dbus-1/dbus-daemon-launch-helper</servicehelper>

  <!-- Write a pid file -->
  <pidfile>/var/run/dbus/pid</pidfile>

  <!-- Enable logging to syslog -->
  <syslog/>

  <!-- Only allow socket-credentials-based authentication -->
  <auth>EXTERNAL</auth>

  <!-- Only listen on a local socket. (abstract=/path/to/socket 
       means use abstract namespace, don't really create filesystem 
       file; only Linux supports this. Use path=/whatever on other 
       systems.) -->
  <listen>unix:path=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket</listen>

  <policy context="default">
    <!-- All users can connect to system bus -->
    <allow user="*"/>

    <!-- Holes must be punched in service configuration files for
         name ownership and sending method calls -->
    <deny own="*"/>
    <deny send_type="method_call" log="true"/>

    <!-- THIS IS THE ONLY WAY TO GET THIS TO WORK
    <allow own="*"/>
    <allow send_type="method_call" log="true"/>
    -->



    <!-- Signals and reply messages (method returns, errors) are allowed
         by default -->
    <allow send_type="signal"/>
    <allow send_requested_reply="true" send_type="method_return"/>
    <allow send_requested_reply="true" send_type="error"/>

    <!-- All messages may be received by default -->
    <allow receive_type="method_call"/>
    <allow receive_type="method_return"/>
    <allow receive_type="error"/>
    <allow receive_type="signal"/>

    <!-- Allow anyone to talk to the message bus -->
    <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.DBus"/>
    <!-- But disallow some specific bus services -->
    <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.DBus"
          send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus"
          send_member="UpdateActivationEnvironment"/>

  </policy>

  <!-- Config files are placed here that among other things, punch 
       holes in the above policy for specific services. -->
  <includedir>system.d</includedir>

  <!-- This is included last so local configuration can override what's 
       in this standard file -->
  <include ignore_missing="yes">system-local.conf</include>

  <include if_selinux_enabled="yes" selinux_root_relative="yes">contexts/dbus_contexts</include>

</busconfig>
```

I absolutely have to use the System bus because I am deploying it on a Raspberry Pi without a GUI, (no x11, and no session bus). I was able to get the Raspberry Pi working only by completely allowing everything on the system bus (security is not nearly as big of a deal on this device). Obviously, there is no way I'm allowing that to occur on my development machine. As background I am using Opensuse 12.2 and the Raspberry Pi is Debian Squeeze. I cannot own the service with my user account, nor root, unless I completely open the permissions up, in that case it works just fine. I will also note that when I completely opened up the system bus, I still had to use root to send messages to the daemon (a terminate command). I'd like the solution to be able to be runnable via a particular user with root having access as well. I am also OK with the solution only allowing the same user and root to send messages to it.

Thanks for any help I'm sure it's a small issue!

Comment: Is there an arduino conf file that you could change?

Comment: The first two conf files I posted is the conf file that is located in system.d. Its called "org.dbus.arduino". No matter what I put in this file, (or even if i copy and paste and put in any other conf file) it doesn't change the permissions to own the service.

Comment: Have you tried putting `<policy user="myUser"> ...` statements in `system.conf` as a happy medium in between deny all and allow all?  I'm not sure of syntax here, or if it will even let you do that... just trying to help.

Comment: or maybe try creating a conf file to match your service - e.g. `com.example.myservice.conf` in `system.d/` with policy you want?

Comment: OK I have 100% confirmed that there is some sort of issue with the individual conf files in system.d/. I did what you said and put the specific service ownership in a <policy user="user"> node INSIDE the system.conf file. That worked. I then removed it, put it in a .conf file inside system.d/ no dice. Does not work. The problem still remains, HOWEVER, this is workable, I'm not 100% sure I want to call this "answered". I'll wait till next week to see if anybody else has any ideas.

Comment: That was just a guess... I don't have any experience with the conf files. It kinda makes sense though that you would have to white list a user or somehow grant more permissions than are present by default. I seem to recall reading something about calling or invoking the conf file to make the policy active but don't ask me where I saw that. Again, no experience. All guess.

Comment: Will it was a good guess and has certainly got the ball rolling. Writing directly to the system.conf file is is a very usable "work around"! It didn't help that It was also failing because i was using com instead of org, but that didn't fix the not reading the conf files from system.d/.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/PolicyKit/Helper_HowTo#The_DBus_policy_file)?

Comment: I had not seen that. A. I read it with a fine tooth and noticed the ".conf" ending on the configuration filename (note the answer to the problem), and B. I found out that you can make it autostart up the service. That is AWESOME. I think if more developers knew about dbus, and what it can do for inter application speaking, (and how easy it is) everybody would be using the bus...

Comment: Glad you got it working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally found the issue. When Dbus looks for configuration files for punching out permissions (like ownerships) the file not only must be in system.d/ but it must also end in .conf.

My configuration file "org.dbus.arduino" should have been "org.dbus.arduino.conf". I removed the code from system.conf. Confirmed I no longer had permissions, created a configuration file at "system.d/org.dbus.arduino.conf", I was granted permissions. I then attempted to rename the file to just "org.dbus.arduino" and confirmed the permissions were denied.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. Thinking using session bus like: Use dbus-launch to launch a session bus and save the returned env into a well-known file. In dbus server and client source the env file to get to be able to connect to the session bus. Do you see any drawback there?

Comment: this helped in 2022

Answer (score 1):

I did the same solution as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23188249/2745495) but I also got it to work with this alternative.

I noticed that in my *system.conf* file, there is this note:

> For local configuration changes, **create a file system-local.conf** or
>   files matching system.d/*.conf in the same directory as this one, with
>   a  element containing configuration directives. These
>   directives can override D-Bus or OS defaults.

Instead of putting a *`<name.of.my.dbus.service>`.conf* under *system.d/*, I was able to make it work by creating a *system-local.conf* in the same directory as the *system.conf*, with the contents like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-Bus Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
  <policy context="default">
    <allow own="dbus.my.own.service"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```