# How to get QDBusConnection::connect() failure reason

Tags: qt, dbus, qtdbus

I'm trying to connect to a D-Bus signal this way:

```
bool result = QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect(
    "foo.bar",  // service
    "/foo/bar", // path 
    "foo.bar",  // interface
    "SignalSomething",
    this,
    SLOT(SignalSomethingSlot()));

if( !result )
{
    // Why!?
}
```

`QDBusConnection::connect()` returns a boolean, how do I get extended error information? If a check `QDBusConnection::lastError()` it returns no useful information (as `QDBusError::isValid()` is `false`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and it turned out that the slot I connected to had the wrong parameter types. They must match according to Qt's [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/qdbusconnection.html#connect) and it looks like `connect()` verifies that, despite not explicitly mentioned.

> **Warning**: The signal will only be delivered to the slot if the parameters match.

I suggest [d-feet](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DFeet) to list signals and check their parameter types. `dbus-monitor` does list signals, paths and such too, but not always the exact type of parameters.

---

**One important observation though:** I fixed the issue in my particular case by using different slot parameters than the actual signal has!

I wanted to connect to a `com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6` signal mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/854836) to detect when the screen in Ubuntu is locked/unlocked. `dbusmonitor` prints the following and `d-feet` shows parameters `(String, Array of [String])`

```
// dbusmonitor output
signal time=1529077633.579984 sender=:1.0 -> destination=(null destination) serial=809 path=/com/ubuntu/Upstart; interface=com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6; member=EventEmitted
   string "desktop-unlock"
   array [
   ]
```

Hence the signal *should* be of type

```
void screenLockChangedUbuntu(QString event, QVector<QString> args) // connect() -> false
```

This however made `connect()` return `false`. The solution was to remove the array parameter from the slot:

```
void screenLockChangedUbuntu(QString event) // works
```

I am aware that the array parameter was always empty, but I cannot explain why it only worked when removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try these tricks:

1) Set **QDBUS_DEBUG** environment variable before running your application.

```
export QDBUS_DEBUG=1
```

2) Start [dbus-monitor](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html) to see what's happening on the bus. You may need to set a global policy to be able to [eavesdrop](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingDBus) system bus depending on your distro.

**Update:**

Are you sure connecting to the system bus succeeded? If it fails you should probably check `system.conf` policy and possibly create own conf in `system.d`. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156941/system-dbus-does-not-allow-punching-out-ownership-with-conf-files) might be helpful.

You could first connect to the system bus with [QDBusConnection::connectToBus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusconnection.html#connectToBus) and check if it succeeded with [QDBusConnection::isConnected](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusconnection.html#isConnected). Only after that you try to connect to the signal and check if that succeeded.

```
QDBusConnection bus = QDBusConnection::connectToBus(QDBusConnection::systemBus, myConnectionName);
if (bus.isConnected())
{
    if(!bus.connect( ... ))
    {
        // Connecting to signal failed
    }
}
else
{
    // Connecting to system bus failed
}
```

Comment: I tried both the tricks but they don't help as the problem is not on the bus but within QtDBus...

Comment: I updated my answer. Suspecting connecting to the system bus doesn't succeed.

Comment: Yes it connects: I'm able to call methods on the same D-Bus interface. I just get an error trying to connect a SLOT to a D-Bus signal. But I don't want to be too specific and troubleshoot my specific scenario. I'd like to know if there is a way to get the reason for the failure.