# Connect to 'PCMAdded' and 'PCMRemoved' signals of bluealsa (Qt)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, bluetooth, dbus

I'm try to build a C++ application in Qt to capture  audio  streams  from Bluetooth devices and play them to an ALSA playback device. This application runs in a Linux-embedded system and communicates with bluez (http://www.bluez.org/) and bluealsa (https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa) via DBus.

What I need to do is being able to listen to the `PCMAdded` and `PCMRemoved` signals sent by the `org.bluealsa.Manager1` interface of the bluealsa service (`org.bluealsa`) through the DBus. For some unknown reason, the connect method fails.

Here is how I do it:

```
manager1 = new QDBusInterface("org.bluealsa",
                              "/org/bluealsa",
                              "org.bluealsa.Manager1",
                              QDBusConnection::systemBus(),
                              this);

qDebug() << "manager1->isValid:" << manager1->isValid(); // YES

if(!manager1->connection().connect(manager1->service(),   //"org.bluealsa",
                                   manager1->path(),      //"/org/bluealsa",
                                   manager1->interface(), //"org.bluealsa.Manager1",
                                   "PCMAdded",
                                   this,
                                   SLOT(PCMAddedSlot(QDBusObjectPath, QVariantMap))),
                                   Qt::QueuedConnection){

    qDebug() << "Failed to connect PCMAdded signal"; // <- FAILS!!!
    qDebug() << "lastError:" << QDBusConnection::systemBus().lastError().message();
}

if(!manager1->connection().connect(manager1->service(),   //"org.bluealsa",
                                   manager1->path(),      //"/org/bluealsa",
                                   manager1->interface(), //"org.bluealsa.Manager1",
                                   "PCMRemoved",
                                   this,
                                   SLOT(PCMRemovedSlot(QDBusObjectPath))),
                                   Qt::QueuedConnection){

    qDebug() << "Failed to connect PCMRemoved signal"; // <- FAILS!!!
    qDebug() << "lastError:" << QDBusConnection::systemBus().lastError().message();
}
```

In the .h file, the definition of the slots are:

```
public Q_SLOTS:
    void PCMAddedSlot(QDBusObjectPath path, QVariantMap props);
    void PCMRemovedSlot(QDBusObjectPath path);
```

I don't know what is wrong, other connections from other services work just fine.

These is a way to know **why** the connection fails? There is this question, but didn't help ([How to get QDBusConnection::connect() failure reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304998/how-to-get-qdbusconnectionconnect-failure-reason)).

Here is the output of the Instrospect command on bluealsa:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluealsa --type=method_call --print-reply /org/bluealsa org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect

method return time=1652969572.610729 sender=:1.3 -> destination=:1.11 serial=14 reply_serial=2
   string "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
                      "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<!-- GDBus 2.62.6 -->
<node>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties">
    <method name="Get">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="s" name="property_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="v" name="value" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetAll">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="properties" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="Set">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="s" name="property_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="v" name="value" direction="in"/>
    </method>
    <signal name="PropertiesChanged">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name"/>
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="changed_properties"/>
      <arg type="as" name="invalidated_properties"/>
    </signal>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable">
    <method name="Introspect">
      <arg type="s" name="xml_data" direction="out"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer">
    <method name="Ping"/>
    <method name="GetMachineId">
      <arg type="s" name="machine_uuid" direction="out"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.bluealsa.Manager1">
    <method name="GetPCMs">
      <arg type="a{oa{sv}}" name="PCMs" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <signal name="PCMAdded">
      <arg type="o" name="path"/>
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="props"/>
    </signal>
    <signal name="PCMRemoved">
      <arg type="o" name="path"/>
    </signal>
  </interface>
</node>
"
```

Additional info:

- setting `QDBUS_DEBUG=1` showed no helpful information.
- `QDBusConnection::systemBus().lastError().message()` shows no errors.
- system bus is connected and working.
- cannot use PulseAudio, must stick with **bluealsa**.
- signals from bluez (`org.bluez`) are recieved correctly (the connect methods work).
- I can use without issues the `GetPCMs` method of the bluealsa `org.bluealsa.Manager1`  interface.
- I cannot use graphical tools (such as d-feet or qdbusviewer) to inspect the DBus, I have only the dbus-* commands.
- Maybe the problem is somehow connected to the configuration files? I tried to disable all security but still doesn't work (https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dbus/2010-October/013654.html).
- Cannot connect to the `PropertiesChanged` signal neither. I use the same code that I wrote for other interfaces (and there it works).

Follows the output of the Qt Creator console:

```
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x66300920) Adding rule: "type='signal',sender='org.bluealsa',path='/org/bluealsa',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',member='PropertiesChanged'"
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x66300920) sending message: QDBusMessage(type=MethodCall, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="GetNameOwner", signature="", contents=("org.bluealsa") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x66300920) got message reply: QDBusMessage(type=MethodReturn, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", signature="s", contents=(":1.3") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x66300920) Watching service "org.bluealsa" for owner changes (current owner: ":1.3" )
Failed to connect PropertiesChangedSlot signal
lastError: ""  

QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x66300920) Adding rule: "type='signal',sender='org.bluealsa',path='/org/bluealsa',interface='org.bluealsa.Manager1',member='PCMAdded'"
Failed to connect PCMAdded signal
lastError: ""

QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x66300920) Adding rule: "type='signal',sender='org.bluealsa',path='/org/bluealsa',interface='org.bluealsa.Manager1',member='PCMRemoved'"Failed to connect PCMRemoved signal
lastError: ""
```

and the output of `dbus-monitor --system`:

```
method call time=1652974083.935035 sender=:1.11 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=20 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=AddMatch
   string "type='signal',sender='org.bluealsa',path='/org/bluealsa',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',member='PropertiesChanged'"
method call time=1652974083.935120 sender=:1.11 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=21 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=AddMatch
   string "type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.DBus',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus',member='NameOwnerChanged',arg0='org.bluealsa'"
method call time=1652974083.935888 sender=:1.11 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=22 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=GetNameOwner
   string "org.bluealsa"
method return time=1652974083.935953 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.11 serial=12 reply_serial=22
   string ":1.3"

method call time=1652974125.821756 sender=:1.11 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=23 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=AddMatch
   string "type='signal',sender='org.bluealsa',path='/org/bluealsa',interface='org.bluealsa.Manager1',member='PCMAdded'"

method call time=1652974160.661667 sender=:1.11 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=24 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=AddMatch
   string "type='signal',sender='org.bluealsa',path='/org/bluealsa',interface='org.bluealsa.Manager1',member='PCMRemoved'"
```

**EDIT**

I can easily see that the signals are sent via dbus-monitor:

```
signal time=1653039761.040063 sender=:1.3 -> destination=(null destination) serial=60 path=/org/bluealsa; interface=org.bluealsa.Manager1; member=PCMRemoved
   object path "/org/bluealsa/hci0/dev_EC_7C_B6_05_AD_0D/a2dpsnk/source"    

method return time=1653039769.432723 sender=:1.3 -> destination=:1.2 serial=61 reply_serial=2869
   array of bytes [
      21 15 02 35
   ]
signal time=1653039769.472354 sender=:1.3 -> destination=(null destination) serial=62 path=/org/bluealsa; interface=org.bluealsa.Manager1; member=PCMAdded
   object path "/org/bluealsa/hci0/dev_EC_7C_B6_05_AD_0D/a2dpsnk/source"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "Device"
         variant             object path "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_EC_7C_B6_05_AD_0D"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "Transport"
         variant             string "A2DP-sink"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "Mode"
         variant             string "source"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "Format"
         variant             uint16 33296
      )
      dict entry(
         string "Channels"
         variant             byte 2
      )
      dict entry(
         string "Sampling"
         variant             uint32 44100
      )
      dict entry(
         string "Codec"
         variant             string "SBC"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "Delay"
         variant             uint16 0
      )
      dict entry(
         string "SoftVolume"
         variant             boolean true
      )
      dict entry(
         string "Volume"
         variant             uint16 32639
      )
   ]
method return time=1653039769.473281 sender=:1.3 -> destination=:1.2 serial=63 reply_serial=2871
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**

I've managed to make it work, by calling the `AddMatch` method on the `org.freedesktop.DBus` interface.
Now the slots are called correcly when the signals `PCMAdded` and `PCMRemoved` are emitted by bluealsa, **BUT** the `connect()` method **still returns false**.

An even stranger thing, the dbus interface is not valid, even if it works perfectly.

Here is how I did:

```
dbus = new QDBusInterface("org.freedesktop.DBus", "/org/freedesktop/DBus", "org.freedesktop.DBus", QDBusConnection::systemBus(), this);

qDebug() << "dbus->isValid:" << dbus->isValid(); // <- FALSE!

AddMatch("type='signal', sender='org.bluealsa', path='/org/bluealsa', interface='org.bluealsa.Manager1', member='PCMRemoved', arg0='org.myapp', arg2=''");
AddMatch("type='signal', sender='org.bluealsa', path='/org/bluealsa', interface='org.bluealsa.Manager1', member='PCMAdded', arg0='org.myapp', arg2=''");
```

where:

```
bool AddMatch(QString str) {

    if (dbus != NULL) {

        QDBusReply<void> reply = dbus->call("AddMatch", str);

        if (reply.isValid()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            qDebug() << reply.error().message() << reply.error().name();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what is wrong, but you can try couple of things:

- Maybe you can check what happens if you connect to the signal over QDBusConnecion rather over QDBusInterface.

```
QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect("org.bluealsa", "/org/bluealsa", "org.bluealsa.Manager1", "PCMAdded", this, SLOT(PCMAddedSlot(QDBusObjectPath, QVariantMap));
```

- Maybe QtDBus has issues with QDBusObjectPath, use QDBusMessage as your slot signature.

```
public Q_SLOTS:
    void PCMAddedSlot(const QDBusMessage& message);
```

and parse the required arguments out of QDBusMessage manually.

Comment: Tried both suggestions, but nothing changed. I somehow made it working by calling the `AddMatch` method on the `org.freedesktop.DBus` interface. Strange thing: the `connect()` still returns false.